# as.type('category') not yielding the desired datatype change from 'float64'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to convert a particular column of a dataframe `df` to a categorical datatype! or what R Programming refers to as a `factor`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1,1,2,2,3,3]]))
df = df.T
df[0].describe()
```

yields

```
count    6.000000
mean     2.000000
std      0.894427
min      1.000000
25%      1.250000
50%      2.000000
75%      2.750000
max      3.000000
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

After I convert to 'category'

```
df[0] = df[0].astype('category')
df[0].describe()
```

yields

```
count     6
unique    3
top       3
freq      2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

**Expected Output:** After I convert the data type of a column to a category by using the right code (which I'm trying to figure out), I want `df[0].describe()` to display something like

```
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [1, 2, 3]
```

I think I kinda know where I'm going wrong. I feel like I need to explicitly mention the different categories or the different levels as I convert to categorical data type. Would love it if you could point me in the right direction doing this.

Can every column having an `object` datatype be considered a `category` datatype? It would be helpful if you can highlight some major differences between the 'object' datatype and 'category'.

Also, while implementing one-hot-encoding for Machine Learning, I understand that, it is used to convert categorical features to numerical features so you can plug them into sci-kit learn. So (in more formal terms) does this mean, one-hot-encoding will help convert a datatype of either `object` or `category` to `int64` datatype?

**QUESTION RESOLVED from comments**: There is a difference between typing df[0] and df[0].describe(), simply printing `df[0]` displayed the datatype as `category`, while, `df[0].describe()` shows it as int64.

Comment: if you type `df[0]` and scroll down you will see what you need

Comment: This is embarrassing.. Why does, df[0].describe() end up displaying something different.. Nevermind. I'm such a noob.

Comment: Do you still need me provide my understating about what the different of cate and object ?

Comment: I would like to know that part! All I know is that a datatype `object` is kind of a datatype where a column may have a mixture of `string` or `int` datatypes. Post it on answers so I can resolve it..

Comment: You can check it ~ :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type it then scroll down

```
df[0]
Out[942]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
Name: 0, dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [1, 2, 3]
```

The different base on my understanding: `category` will carry on the original level , and this is good trick when you do some data `slice` , but you do not want to keep the `value` but you want the `level` in output.

Before change to `category`:

```
df[0].value_counts()
Out[947]: 
3    2
2    2
1    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64


df1=df.iloc[2:3]
df1[0].value_counts()
Out[956]: 
2    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

After change to category:

```
df[0] = df[0].astype('category')
df1=df.iloc[2:3]
df1
Out[953]: 
   0
2  2


df1[0].value_counts()

Out[954]: 
2    1
3    0
1    0
```